# OSX 10.9.2: Stuck at quick user switch

Tags: macos

I want to quick switch to the other user in the system, but this login screen has stay there for almost half an hour

[image]

Can I cancel the login via command line or other keyboard combination? I can ssh into the box as an admin

/EDIT: I want avoid reboot or shutdown

Comment: maybe try restarting the WindowServer process? (sudo killall -HUP WindowServer)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turned out the computer was looking for an external hard drive to mount that wasn't connected properly. If you have any external hard drives, you may want to try unplugging them and then doing a forced restart?

Answer (score 0):

My issue began after migrating from a time machine backup (10.9.2) so I can't imagine there's an OS conflict. I've done many migrations from time machine, and Mac to Mac (I'm no novice) and never experienced this issue. The external drive used for the backup isn't connected when I attempt to fast user switch, so at the moment I can't imagine what the system is stuck looking for since the exact data exist for all the users on my system. There are 3 users (A,B,C) on my system, and this issue only affect trying to fast user switch from 1 user to another (lets say A to B). The 3rd user C I can fast user switch to A or B without issue; so the issue lies between users A & B (or B to A). I can go from C to A or B though...weird.